# How do I make Notepad++ run my current Python 3 script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++

When I coded off of Notepad++ a few years ago, a friend of mine set it up so I could run it by doing CTRL+R or F5 and it would run the script that I had open at that time on Notepad++. Every google search I've followed so far on doing this hasn't worked, though most of them were quite dated. Alot of them result in me opening a blank .py application which does not run my code.

Do I need to download Python to my PATH, as suggested in the installer? The FULL_CURRENT_PATH fix hasn't worked.

Comment: go through the link https://silentcrash.com/2016/12/run-python-script-notepad/

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this. Moved my Python folder into C: and made it point to the following:

cmd /k "C:\Python\Python37\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

This runs the python script in a command prompt, rather than a .py executable. But it works just the same.